# How to store value in one column by calculating the value of another columns of same table in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an entity class called ItemEntity where there are 2 columns: price and quantity. I want to add a third column called amuount in such a way that `amount = rate*quantity`. I have done it this way:

Here is the full entity class:

```
namespace Services.Common.Billing.Entities;

    public class ItemEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        public int FeeType { get; set; }
        public int FeeSchedule { get; set; }
        public int FeeUnit { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public Decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Rate(US$)")]
        public Decimal Rate { get; set; }
        public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the dbContext class:

```
    public class BillingDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public BillingDbContext(DbContextOptions<BillingDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<ItemEntity>? Items { get; set; }

        //Any seed data goes here
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemEntity>().Property(e => e.Amount).HasComputedColumnSql("Items.Rate * Items.Quantity", stored: true);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way the amount is saved to the database automatically while the entity class is used in API? The value of the amount should be `quantity*rate`.

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns) if database supports it, for example with shadow property:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property<decimal>("AmountCol")
    .HasComputedColumnSql("Rate * Quantity", stored: true);
```

Note that `stored: true` results in column that is computed on every update of the row, and is stored on disk alongside regular columns, for `false` (default)  a virtual computed column is created, whose value is computed every time it is fetched from the database.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Just to know, can't I add this logic in the entity class itself?

Comment: @saurav.rox AFAIK - no.

Comment: I tried it like this: 
In Entity class: public Decimal? Amount { get; set; }
In DBContextSnapshot: modelBuilder.Entity<ItemEntity>().Property<decimal>("Amount").HasComputedColumnSql("Rate * Quantity", stored: true);

But it is throwing an error as:    The shared-type entity type 'Services.Common.Billing.Entities.ItemEntity' cannot be added because the model already contains an entity type with the same name, but with a different CLR type 'Dictionary<string, object>'. Ensure all entity type names are unique.

Comment: @saurav.rox either use different names for column and property or hack it by changing property to be one with setter and backing field and getter returning  `Rate * Quantity`.

Comment: @saurav.rox sorry, misread the comment. 1) it seems that a full repro is missing 2) why `decimal?` in the first place, fix the types between column and entity 3) If you want to use the auto-property in C# part then `modelBuilder.Entity<ItemEntity>().Property(e => e.Amount).Has ....`

Comment: Corrected as suggested. But still the same error. Could you please shade some light?

Here is the code:
In Entity Class: `public Decimal Amount { get; set; }`

in DbContext:  `modelBuilder.Entity<ItemEntity>().Property(e => e.Amount).HasComputedColumnSql("Rate * Quantity", stored: true);`

Comment: @saurav.rox I will need a full [mre] then.

Comment: Question has been modified with full code. Maybe it will be convenient for you to check it now. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @saurav.rox TBH I'm a bit surprised why have you shared the migration. The code I've provided should be added to your context class in override of `OnModelCreating` method - see the [Use fluent API to configure a model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#use-fluent-api-to-configure-a-model) doc. Please share a [mre] with the context class.

Comment: I have corrected my question and have updated it with what you have suggested. However, a new error is seen when the above code is used. The error says `Npgsql.PostgresException: '42P01: missing FROM-clause entry for table "items"'`. The database is Postgres. Could you please help?